# Open collected html in new tab

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a reporting system on my site, and i want to do something like that. Send ajax with process bar, my server side will collect needed data turn them in html, and send me back, on ajax success i`d like to close procccess bar and open in new browser tab my response data. Is it possible? If yes, give me advice please how can i do this? I am interested in the last step when data already collected and stored in my javascript var, i just need represent it in new tab.

I forgot about one nuance report output like pdf file not like html=)

Comment: What do you mean by new "tab"? Do you mean new Browser tab? Or UI tab like in jQuery UI tabs?

Comment: i mean, new browser tab.

Comment: You could try using `var w = window.open("", ""); w.document.open(); w.write(YOUR_DATA); w.document.close();` or something similar...but you won't be able to control whether this is opened in a window or tab. Although this will not automatically have the resources that your main page does (like CSS stylesheets and Javascript files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is a

```
window.open(url, window name, attributes...)
```

Tabs are managed by browsers and depending on user's setting, your call will open a URL in a new tab or in a new window; usually in a new tab.

```
var newWindow = window.open("","","status");

function fillNewWindow() {
    // newWindow.focus()
    var newContent = "<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>A New Doc</TITLE></HEAD>";
    newContent += "<BODY><H1>This document is brand new.</H1>";
    newContent += "</BODY></HTML>"";
    newWindow.document.write(newContent);
    newWindow.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is **not possible** to control if the page will be owpened in a tab vs a new window, but usually in modern browsers `window.open(url, page_title);` opens in a new tab.

Once you send a third parameter to `window.open`, like `'width=850,height=625'`, it will open in a new window.